# Problem with Detached object in JPA2

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA2 and Hibernate implementation. I'm trying to persist a User object, which got a List of Authorities

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL)
private List<UserAuthority> userAuthorities;
```

In my service there is :

```
UserAuthority userAuthority = new UserAuthority();
userAuthority.setAuthority(authorityDao.getByName(Authorities.ROLE_USER
                .toString()));
userAuthority.setUser(user);
List<UserAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<UserAuthority>();
authorities.add(userAuthority);
user.setUserAuthorities(authorities);
userDao.persist(user);
```

The `"getByName"` method in `authorityDao` finds a `ROLE_USER` in my database. Both userDao and authorityDao got @Transactional annotations. Now when I try to call     `userDao.persist(user)` I got an exception. Why and how solve it?

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: pl.flamewars.entity.Authority; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: pl.flamewars.entity.Authority
```

Thanks

Dawid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is one of the many complications that arise from using transactional dao methods (with spring).

The usual practice is to have your service methods annotated with `@Transactional`.

In your case, your `Authority` object appears to be obtained from a different session, and hence it is detached when you call `persist()`. So:

- Get rid of `@Transactional` on DAO methods and place it on service methods instead
- Give `merge(..)` a try (instead of `persist()`)

Comment: I'm gonna try it today later, and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you pass some detached entity to persist..

```
userAuthority.setAuthority(authorityDao.getByName(Authorities.ROLE_USER
                .toString()));
```

This code actually loads the persisted entity and sets to the new `userAuthority`, instead of this assign the new Authority object or revisit the cascade mapping part of `Authority` in `UserAuthority`